# How to check if matching words is found in a string in Lua?

Tags: string, lua, find, match

Using:

```
if string.find(message.content, "hi") then
  global:printError("[INFO] Someone sent you hi")
  
end
```

Works good, however I'd like to give it a word list to actually trigger the print message.

EG: hello,salut,bonjour,hi,hola,
And my `message.content = hi comment va tu ? I can say hello, speak spanish hola`
If any of the words is found in the string trigger the message.

How do I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a list of greetings and iterate over the list directly. For example:

local greetings = { "hello", "salut", "bonjour", "hola", "hi" }

```
for _,v in pairs(greetings) do
if v == message.content then
-- do something
 break
 end
end
```

Comment: Hello and thank you.
Unfortunately that doesn't works for my needs, at least partially the list works just fine as it should but if the  ```message.content``` is 12365 hello 123654 nothing will happen
however, if it's only hello or salut or bonjour it works just fine as it should.
The approch I would see similar in c# would be ```if string.contains("")``` 
No idea on how it works with LUA, new to this.

Comment: @LearningHow2Code just replace `v == message.content` with `message.content:find(v)` (works fine as long as `v` contains no magic characters)

Comment: @LMB this worked just fine as It should thank you.
You can repost it as an answer if you wish so I can select it as resolved.
Otherwise I'll mark EmilioW answer instead.